# IF statement newbie

Tags: php

```
                <?php 

                if ($user->getProfile()->get('title')="Canon"); {
                echo "Test1"; }
                else {
                echo "Test2"; }

                ?>
```

This is causing my site to break, is there an obvious mistake?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`=` is an *assignment*, you want `==` for a comparison.

You also shouldn't have a `;` between `)` and `{`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
  <?php 

            if ( ($user->getProfile()->get('title')) == "Canon" ){ 
              echo "Test1";
            }
            else {
            echo "Test2"; 
            }

            ?>
```

First of all You need a comparison '==' and not an assigning '='

And then You have a syntax error with a ';' after the condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `=` sign to `==` as the first one **assigns** a values while the latter one **compares** it.

And also, you don't need to terminate the `if` statement with a semicolon

```
if ($user->getProfile()->get('title') == "Canon") /* note that there is no semicolon here */ 
{ echo "Test1"; }
            else 
{ echo "Test2"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php 

            if ($user->getProfile()->get('title')=="Canon") {
                echo "Test1"; 
            }

            else {
                echo "Test2"; 
            }


            ?>
```

Try this.